# Implode all input value in form submit

Tags: php, forms

I have form that display image and input using foreach and want to get its value on form submit so I can implode it and save to database but not sure how can I do this. so far, the only value I get on form submit is the value of the last field. here is my code to display the form:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">

        <?php
            # Prepare the SELECT Query
            $productimage = explode ("|", $productimage);
            foreach ($productimage as $imgfile) {
                echo '<div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="product-img">
                                    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="../content/uploads/' . $imgfile . '" width="120" height="120" />
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="imgtitle">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="imgurl" value="' . $imgfile . '">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>';
            }
        ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-saveimg">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>
    </div>  
</form>
```

On form submit, I'm going to get the POST value using this code:

```
if ( isset($_POST['btn-saveimg']) ) {

    $imgurlUpdate = $_POST['imgurl'];
    $imgtitleUpdate = $_POST['imgtitle'];

    $arr = array($imgurlUpdate,'#',$imgtitleUpdate);

    print_r($arr);
}
```

on print_r, the only result I get is the last value of the form.

```
Array ( [0] => image4.jpg [1] => # [2] => title4 )
```

I'm trying to achieve something like this result using implode:

```
image1.jpg#title1|image2.jpg#title2|image3.jpg#title3|image4.jpg#title4
```

that I can save into a database if for example I have 4 image. Any idea?

Comment: your print_r() output?

Comment: Hey @MuhammadUsman thanks for asking. I just updated my question and add the output of print_r()

Comment: the output of print_r($_POST) please?

Answer (score 1):

i think the problem is in the input tag that you have used, you are storing multiple imgurl & imgtitle. you should have store the name value in array.

```
'<div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="product-img">
                                <img class="img-thumbnail" src="../content/uploads/' . $imgfile . '" width="120" height="120" />
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="imgtitle[]">
                                <input type="hidden" name="imgurl[]" value="' . $imgfile . '">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>';'
```

when you fetch the value on php side fetch value as an array element. 
i hope this helps.